# How to join() words from a string?

Tags: python, string

I want to  transform the string `'one two three'` into `one_two_three`.

I've tried `"_".join('one two three')`, but that gives me `o_n_e_ _t_w_o_ _t_h_r_e_e_`...

how do I insert the `"_"` only at spaces between words in a string?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use string's replace method:

```
'one two three'.replace(' ', '_')
# 'one_two_three'
```

---

`str.join` method takes an iterable as an argument and concatenate the strings in the iterable, string by itself is an iterable so you will separate each character by the `_` you specified, if you directly call `_.join(some string)`.

Answer (score 5):

You can also split/join:

```
'_'.join('one two three'.split())
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you want to use join only , so you can do like this`test="test string".split() 
"_".join(test)`
This will give you output as "test_string".